# Eigenvalues of complex $2×2$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be complex  $2×2$  matrices s.t. $A^2=0$. Which of the following statements are true?
>
> 1. $PAP^{-1}$ is diagonal for some $2×2$ real matrix $P$.
> 2. $A$ has $2$ distinct eigenvalues in $\Bbb C$.
> 3. $A$ has $1$ eigenvalue in $\Bbb C$ with multiplicity $2$.
> 4. $Av=v$ for $v\in \Bbb C^2 ,v≠0$.

Comment: not getting any A s.t. A^2=0.

Comment: where to begin ....please suggest me...........

Comment: Take $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&a\\-a&-a\end{pmatrix}$ for any $a\in\mathbb{C}$, for exmaple.

Comment: 2 is wrong ........ 3 is correct..........

Comment: That's right. Can you prove it?

Comment: what about 1 and 4..............

Comment: Check that $(PAP^{-1})^2=PA^2P^{-1}$. What can you conclude about 1?

Comment: I can't find 4  but1 is looking right

Comment: where to begin ....please suggest me  for  4...

Answer (score 1):

I will sum the above discussion here:
1. Show that $(PAP^{-1})^2=PA^2P^{-1}$. Since $A^2=0$, what can you conclude about $A$, if indeed there exists such $P$?
2. You said that it is wrong. Can you show why? (Hint: what is the def of an eigenvalue?)
3. Is coorect, as you said. It should follow from the proof you used in 2.
4. If there esists $v\in\mathbb{C}^2$ such that $Av=v$, what is $A^2v$? can that happen?

Comment: 4 is wrong still not getting 1.....

Comment: @Dennis,I am new in mathematics field , so as far as I know about $2$,since $A^2=0$ , so $A$ will satisfy the equation $x^2=0$. So minimal polynomial of $A$ will divide this polynomial $x^2$.If A has two distinct eigenvalues then the minimal polynomial will not divide $x^2$.so $2$ false. $3$ will be true against this logic.Am I right? One thing I want to clarify I am not the person who asked the question,I made it because our name is same.

Comment: please guide me for 1..........

Comment: If $D$ is diagonal and $D^2=0$, then what is $D$?

Comment: D is not nilpotent.. am i right??

Comment: $D$ is nilpotent since $D^2=0$, but $D$ is *diagonal*. Can you find $D$?

Comment: D is nilpotent then D can't be diagonal

Comment: If $D=\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{pmatrix}$ and $D^2=0$, then what are $a,b$?

Comment: a=0 b=0,A can be zero matrix there is no limtation..

Comment: @p.haz: I got it.. option a is wrong..

Comment: @p.haz: thanks sir.....

Comment: I got it.. option a is wrong.. 
thanks sir....

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is a nilpotent matrix, so it has only $0$ as eigenvector with multiplicity $2$.